# Unable to download PDF forms in IE10. Error: xyz.pdf couldn't be downloaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I have created a ASP.NET site that at the end generates the PDF forms and displays it to the user.

This is working fine in IE8 version but it's not working in IE10. It gives error ".PDF couldn't be downloaded". It gives same error even when I change browser mode to IE8 using f12.

I am using the following snippet to display PDF and the PDF is created using itextsharp:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.Charset = null;
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; Filename= " + FileName);
Response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
Response.Flush();
Response.Close();
```

Filepath is the path of the PDF file.

Hoping someone can help me resolve this problem.

Comment: I believe I've answered this elsewhere already: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16842173/931274

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar behavior - 
After fighting this issue for about 12 hours what worked for me:

Changing response header from

> Content-Type: application/application/vnd.ms-excel

To

> Content-Type: application/octet-stream

**Note that I had another an unmentioned symptom:** I was setting

> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Inventory_10-10-2013.xls"

Despite that setting IE used the file name from the URL (so it said "getInventory couldn't be downloaded" - and it saved the wrongly named file in the downloads folder!).

When I changed the 'Content-Type' IE started honoring the file name from the header.

For the record here are all the response headers that I'm setting:

- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
- Pragma: Public
- Expires: Fri, 11 Oct 2013 16:33:38 GMT
- Cache-Control: max-age=1
- Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Inventory_10-10-2013.xls"
- Content-Transfer-Encoding: BINARY
- Set-Cookie: fileDownload=true; path=/
- Content-Type: application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8
- Content-Length: 7680
- Date: Thu, 10 Oct 2013 16:33:38 GMT