# Export to excel using Java working in IE8 & IE9 but not in IE10

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have done export to excel coding. I have used both `XSSFWorkBook` and `HSSWorkBook` to support both .xls and .xlsx formats, such as:

```
Workbook[] wbs = new Workbook[] { new HSSFWorkbook(), new XSSFWorkbook() };
```

Also to export in excel, have set the Content type as follows:

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
```

I am able to successfully export in both IE8 and IE9, but when I try to export excel using IE10 then instead of excel notepad opens with some data. How to make it work in all versions of IE? I am not getting which snippet is used which is acting browser version specific. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is related to java or java-ee and not in the export process (that is run on server and not on the web browser).

You need to set the response headers that makes IE10 download the content instead of opening it with some program.

This question might help you [IE 10 - File download issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655566/ie-10-file-download-issues/19302629#19302629)