# ASP.NET MVC cannot stream files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, openxml-sdk

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 site that creates an excel file using `OPEN XML SDK`. I simply point the hyperlink to the proper controller and it generates the OPEN XML excel document and writes the stream to response header and done. In IE 9 and Chrome this works fine. File gets downloaded with the given file name and proper contents. However, just recently I upgraded my browser to IE 10 and now instead of downloading the file and opening up in excel I get the error that `could not open 'URI'`. When I click ok it gives another error: `Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'URI'. There are several possible reasons:`

I don't understand why this would work in IE 9 and chrome and not in IE 10. I debugged the response headers with fiddlers and it has the proper content type, and content length set:

`Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

`Content Disposition: attachment; filename=result.xlsx`

`Content length: 1232`

Is there something that I am missing?

Code snippet: This all is part of

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
...
....
..
    extention = "xlsx";
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                                    String.Format("attachment; filename={0}.{1}", fileName, extention));
    response.AddHeader("Content-Length", mem.Length.ToString());
    mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // Go back to the begining.
    mem.CopyTo(response.OutputStream);
    context.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

Comment: Are you delivering the content via SSL?  Also, what are the several possible reasons it lists?

Comment: `writes the stream to response header and done`, can you show the code?

Comment: Please include a minimal example of the code you are using

Comment: Please, show some code... this answer solved a similar problem for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655566/ie-10-file-download-issues

Comment: @xDaevax: I am seeing the same problem without SSL. I doesn't say any possible reasons.

Comment: @Mark: Added some code.

Comment: @celerno: I am using CompleteRequest(), doesn't help.

Comment: @arserbin3: added relevant pieces.

Comment: Can anyone provide help?

Comment: @cchdev answer is the correct way to transmit a file in ASP.NET MVC.  I don't know of a valid reason for not using the Controller.File method. In short you shouldn't be implementing it this way

Comment: @Mick: we have an wrapper which based on request headers will response with  json/xml/excel/csv/tsv/dsv. I believe it's an ie 10 bug because the same code works in ie 11 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, [`Controller.File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505200(v=vs.118).aspx) works for me with ASP.NET MVC 4 and IE 10:

```
public class DownloadController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetFile()
    {
        ...

        mem.Position = 0;

        return File(
            mem, 
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", 
            "result.xlsx");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

So I have been browsing the MVC source code at CodePlex and found a few implementation details that differ from your code snippet:

- `Content-Length` header is never set
- Instead of calling `Stream.CopyTo`, they use a simple `Stream.Read`, `Stream.Write` loop with buffer size of `0x1000`
- When setting `Content-Disposition` header, they check whether file download name contains UTF-8 chars, and if so, encode them according to RFC 2231. See [`ContentDispositionUtil.GetHeaderValue`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/FileResult.cs)
- `context.HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` is never called

Now you could try applying these changes one by one and see which one makes it work with IE 10.

Comment: Although I tried this as well but couldn't get it to work. I am accepting this as the answer as it was the best attempt to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's an IE10 bug. But maybe you still can work around it.

Based on [this post](http://sharepoint-community.net/forum/topics/can-t-open-excel-files) and a few others.
Please check that:

1. Both full URI and the filename of `Content Disposition` header do not contains special symbols and that their lengths are less than 105. Just use regular A-Za-z0-9 symbols for instance.
2. Try to add "X-UA-Compatible" HTTP header with "IE=9" value.

Comment: Try also to play with Excel file type settings. See **Let me fix it myself** section of MS kb http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162059/en

Answer (score 0):

try these MIME types:-
for old version:-

```
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.xls");
```

for 2007:-

```
Response.ContentType = "application/application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=result.xlsx");
```

for csv files which you need to open in excel is:-

```
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "Attachment;Filename=myfile.csv"
```

in last you can try:-

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=result.xlsx");
```

thanks