# IE11 writes HTML in Response.BinaryWrite instead of byte() content

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-11

I have an ASP.NET (Framework 2.0) website which generates a CSV file and propmpts the user to Save or Open this file (IE native pop-up window). Recently some users upgraded their IE to version 11 and they get the file with HTML as content and not the actual CSV-style rows.
This is working in IE9 and below.

Code for Response.BinaryWrite:

```
Response.Buffer = False
Response.ClearContent()
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=FileExport.csv")
Response.BinaryWrite(Session("nExport"))
Session("nExport") = Nothing
Response.Flush()
Response.Close()
Response.End()
' Session("nExport") contains Byte()
```

Expected file content:

```
NR;FirstName;LastName
1;Bilbo;Baggins
```

File content if I select Save or Open:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"" ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"">"

"<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"" >"
<head><title>
"   Export"
</title></head>
<body>
"    <form name=""form1"" method=""post"" action=""nExport.aspx?ID=RGVwbjsu3GFyamkyMDEz"" id=""form1"">"
<div>
"<input type=""hidden"" name=""__VIEWSTATE"" id=""__VIEWSTATE"" value=""/wEPDwUJNzgzNDMwNTMzZGSmoL1exQ/68hIbp0DWxDDjlt6wAA=="" />"
    </div>

    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** additional information from the user is that another (similar) CSV file download is working correctly. I will have to investigate some more, code for both downloads is the same.

**Edit 2:**
It seems to be working on UAT server, the solution was removing Response.End and Response.Close and use HttpApplication.CompleteRequest, as per this question [ie-10-file-download-issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16842173/2269003). Will have to investigate more and try on production servers.

```
Dim httpApp As New HttpApplication
httpApp.CompleteRequest()
'Response.Close()
'Response.End()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm a working solution on the production server also. As the comment from [stun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/138284/stun) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16842173/2269003) suggests I left Response.Close and Response.End after CompleteRequest.

This is the new Response method:

```
Response.Buffer = False
Response.ClearContent()
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=FileExport.csv")
Response.BinaryWrite(Session("nExport"))
Session("nExport") = Nothing
Response.Flush()

HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()

Response.Close()
Response.End()
```

**Edit:** just a fix, using HttpContext.Current not making a new HttpApplication.