# IE download issue with large file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, zip

I am building application in the Asp.net MVC and I have some features to download zip files of more than 50 MB. All is working fine but in IE10,11 version zip file download more than 40MB is giving error and not downloading. It's giving error like *download was interrupted*. 
For your information I am using IONIC.DLL for zipping the file. It's working good in all other browsers. I am attaching the sample code as well with this.

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.BufferOutput = false;  // for large files
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=Documents.zip");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", "632620");

        using (var zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (!file.Contains(":")) continue;
                var filename = file.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
                var fileUrl = Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Uploads/{0}MyLib/{1}", Test, filename));

                //zipping current file
                zip.AddFile(fileUrl, "Document");
            }    
            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        }
```

Comment: Do you `Response.Close()` or `Response.End()` after this? Is it the whole method?

Comment: You are probably facing this issue because the using statement. Try flushing the response stream right after the Save method. Also check for an overload of Save which does not close the output stream

Comment: Yes @YeldarKurmangaliyev I was using Response.Close() after the using {} statement. I removed it and it start working correctly in IE as well. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: @OguzOzgul Thanks for the hint

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE 10 - File download issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655566/ie-10-file-download-issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting my answer. After trying all the things I removed code line of `Response.Close()` from the end the method. Reason was very simple I was not storing Zipped file to any other location on server so meanwhile it will be stored in Response object and when Response.Close() will be executed big size files will be not downloaded yet. So it will give error like Download was inturrupted.
Thanks @Yeldar and @Oguz for your kind help.